# How add Splider Grid extesnion

Tags: javascript, jquery, splidejs

I am trying add splide grid extension and performed below action

Added `jquery.min.js?v=3.7.0` and `splide-extension-grid.min.js?v=1` and Splide function grid as below.

I followed the installation way from Splide : https://splidejs.com/extensions/grid/
But there is no grids in the splide. I am not sure about Extension used: `window.splide.Grid`

```js
jQuery(function($){

/*import Splide from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/@splidejs/splide@2.4.21"
import Grid from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/@splidejs/splide-extension-grid@0.2.0"*/

new Splide( '#exmpale-slick', {
    type: 'loop', // スライダーの種類 @type: { string }, default: 'slide'
    height: '20rem', // スライダーの高さ @type: { number }, default: ０
  gap: '1em', // スライド間のギャップサイズ @type: { number|string }, default: ０
    perPage: 2, // 1ページに表示するスライドの数 @type: { number }, default: ０
    perMove: 1, // スライダーが移動するスライドの数 @type: { number }, default: ０
    grid: {
    dimensions: [ [ 2, 0.5 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ]], // 配列としてのディメンション（行と列）のコレクション @type: { Array|boolean }, default: false
    gap: { // オブジェクトとしての行と列のギャップサイズ @type: { Object }, default: {}
      row: '1em', // 行の数 @type: { number }, default: 1
            col: '1em' // 列の数 @type: { number }, default: 1
    }
    },
    breakpoints: {  // ブレークポイントの定義
        600: {
            height: '10rem',
            perPage: 1,
            grid: {
                dimensions: [ [ 2, 2 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 3, 1 ] ],
        gap: {
          row: '.5em',
          col: '.5em'
        }
            }
        }
    }
} ).mount( window.splide.Grid );

});
```

HTML below:

```html
    <section class="Gridwraper">
    <div class="GridSet">
      <div class="Gridset view view-new ">
         <div class="view-header">
            <p>Title</p>
         </div>
         <div class="splide" id="exmpale-slick">
            <div class="splide__track">
               <ul class="splide__list">
                  <li class="p-splide__slide splide__slide">
                     <a href="https://www.example.com">
                        <span class="_img-lbl">
                           <h3> image label 1 </h3>
                        </span>
                        <p class="img-txt">image text 1</p>
                        <img loading="lazy" class="img-full" src="image1.jpg" alt="">
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="p-splide__slide splide__slide">
                     <a href="https://www.example.com">
                        <span class="_img-lbl">
                           <h3> image label 2 </h3>
                        </span>
                        <p class="img-txt">image text 2</p>
                        <img loading="lazy" class="img-full" src="image2.jpg" alt="">
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="p-splide__slide splide__slide">
                     <a href="https://www.example.com">
                        <span class="_img-lbl">
                           <h3> image label 3 </h3>
                        </span>
                        <p class="img-txt">image text 3</p>
                        <img loading="lazy" class="img-full" src="image3.jpg" alt="">
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="p-splide__slide splide__slide">
                     <a href="https://www.example.com">
                        <span class="_img-lbl">
                           <h3> image label 4 </h3>
                        </span>
                        <p class="img-txt">image text 4</p>
                        <img loading="lazy" class="img-full" src="image4.jpg" alt="">
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="p-splide__slide splide__slide">
                     <a href="https://www.example.com">
                        <span class="_img-lbl">
                           <h3> image label 5 </h3>
                        </span>
                        <p class="img-txt">image text 5</p>
                        <img loading="lazy" class="img-full" src="image5.jpg" alt="">
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="p-splide__slide splide__slide">
                     <a href="https://www.example.com">
                        <span class="_img-lbl">
                           <h3> image label 6 </h3>
                        </span>
                        <p class="img-txt">image text 6</p>
                        <img loading="lazy" class="img-full" src="image6.jpg" alt="">
                     </a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

Tried calling jquery manually

Answer (score 1):

Please replace this "window.splide.Grid" by "window.splide.Extensions"
Here is my example slide code:

```
var listPlaceSlide = new Splide(listPlace, {
                grid: {
                    rows: 2,
                    cols: 2,
                    gap : {
                        row: '20px',
                        col: '20px',
                    },
                },
            });
            listPlaceSlide.mount(window.splide.Extensions);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the missing detail!
I don't know why this isn't in official docs.